# HTML Bootstrap - Labels and checkboxes in a grid like structure

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve the below design using bootstrap and html

I have tried all ways but i am unable to either ways the design is not working. Below code. Please advise. I was not able to get it through bootstrap so tried with HTML CSS. :

```css
body {
  font-size:1.5em;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  background:white;
}
.label-check input {  display:none; }

.label-check label::before {
  width: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  transition: color .3s ease;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #cccccc;
}
.label-check label:hover::before {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #6286d0;
}
.label-check [type='checkbox']:checked + label::before,
.label-check [type='radio']:checked    + label::before{ 
  color: #056dce;
}
```

```html
<div class="label-check">
  <p class="m3">File Type</p>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
    <label for="check1_Opt1">jpg</label>
    <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt2" checked>
    <label for="check1_Opt2">pdf</label>
    <label for="check1_Opt1">4</label>
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt2" checked>
    <label for="check1_Opt2">mp4</label>
    <label for="check1_Opt1">6</label>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
  <p class="m3">Orientation</p>
Horizontal              &#10696; <br/>
Vertical             &#10696; <br/>
Square             &#10696; <br/>
 <br/>
```

Comment: .label-check input {  display:none; }  -- why this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for a bootstrap grid solution you can try the below code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="label-check container">
  <p class="m3">File Type</p>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">jpg</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">pdf</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">tif</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">docx</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">png</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkGrp1" id="check1_Opt1">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">doc</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col text-right">
          <label for="check1_Opt1">2</label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <p class="m3">Orientation</p>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Horizontal
    </div>

    <div class="col text-right">
      &#10696;
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      Vertical
    </div>

    <div class="col text-right">
      &#10696;
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      Square
    </div>

    <div class="col text-right">
      &#10696;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```